# How to launch one pod on each node without using daemonset on a subgroup of all nodes in a cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, high-availability

Imagine that we have a cluster with 10 nodes and we want to launch a replica of an application on 3 of these nodes, how to do it?

I was thinking about it and I came up with the below solutions but each has a problem:

- Label those 3 nodes and use that label in the application with replicas=3 but we might end up with two replicas on one node (for High Availability I want to prevent this).
- Label those 3 nodes and use daemonset and use that label in daemonset but then we will have 7 pods in pending mode.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: I'd create an ordinary Deployment and set `replicas: 3`; they will get scheduled somewhere in the cluster without you needing to worry about which nodes in particular.  Is there anything special about the 3 nodes you want to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Label those 3 nodes and use that label in the application with replicas=3 but we might end up with two replicas on one node (for High Availability I want to prevent this).

You may use podAntiAffinity rules, or topologySpreadConstraints, to avoid 2 Pods starting on the same node

> Label those 3 nodes and use daemonset and use that label in daemonset but then we will have 7 pods in pending mode.

If your DeamonSet nodeSelector matches 3 nodes, the scheduler would stick to these nodes. There shouldn't be Pods stuck in Pending.

Both solutions sounds good. Maybe using a Deployment + affinities would be more reliable: with a DaemonSet, if one of your node fails, the third replica would not be re-scheduled until you fix that node. Which may or may not be an issue ... up to you.